# Multiple inputs in a custom GF_Field

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms, wordpress-plugin-creation

I’m trying to create a custom field that collects 3 data points for a direct debit payment method.

Here’s the class:

```
<?php

/**
 * @author BAKKBONE Australia
 * @package ddmwgfFields
 * @license GNU General Public License (GPL) 3.0
**/

defined("DDMWGF_EXEC") or die("Silence is golden");

class DDMWGF_Field_Bank extends GF_Field {
    
    public $type = 'direct_debit_account';
    
    public function get_field_container_tag( $form ) {

        if ( GFCommon::is_legacy_markup_enabled( $form ) ) {
            return parent::get_field_container_tag( $form );
        }

        return 'fieldset';

    }
    
    public function get_form_editor_field_title() {
        return esc_attr__('Direct Debit Account', 'direct-debit-merchant-warrior-for-gravity-forms');
    }
    
    public function get_form_editor_field_description() {
        return esc_attr__( 'Allows users to enter bank details for a Direct Debit with Merchant Warrior.', 'direct-debit-merchant-warrior-for-gravity-forms' );
    }
    
    public function get_form_editor_field_icon() {
        return 'gform-icon--total';
    }
    
    public function is_conditional_logic_supported() {
        return true;
    }
    
    public function get_required_inputs_ids() {
        return array( '1', '2', '3' );
    }
    
    public function get_form_editor_button() {
        return array(
            'group' => 'pricing_fields',
            'text'  => $this->get_form_editor_field_title()
        );
    }
    
    function get_form_editor_field_settings() {
        return array(
            'label_setting',
            'description_setting',
            'rules_setting',
            'label_placement_setting',
            'error_message_setting',
            'css_class_setting',
            'admin_label_setting',
            'visibility_setting',
            'conditional_logic_field_setting',
        );
    }
    
    public function is_value_submission_array() {
        return true;
    }
    
    public function get_field_input( $form, $value = '', $entry = null ) {

        $is_entry_detail = $this->is_entry_detail();
        $is_form_editor  = $this->is_form_editor();
        $is_admin = $is_entry_detail || $is_form_editor;

        $form_id  = $form['id'];
        $id       = intval( $this->id );
        $field_id = $is_entry_detail || $is_form_editor || $form_id == 0 ? "input_$id" : 'input_' . $form_id . "_$id";
        $form_id  = ( $is_entry_detail || $is_form_editor ) && empty( $form_id ) ? rgget( 'id' ) : $form_id;

        $class_suffix = rgget('view') == 'entry' ? '_admin' : '';
        $class        = $class_suffix;
        $class        = esc_attr( $class );

        $disabled_text = $is_form_editor ? "disabled='disabled'" : '';
        $class_suffix  = $is_entry_detail ? '_admin' : '';

        $form_sub_label_placement = rgar( $form, 'subLabelPlacement' );
        $field_sub_label_placement = $this->subLabelPlacement;
        $is_sub_label_above       = $field_sub_label_placement == 'above' || ( empty( $field_sub_label_placement ) && $form_sub_label_placement == 'above' );
        $sub_label_class          = $field_sub_label_placement == 'hidden_label' ? "hidden_sub_label screen-reader-text" : '';

        $bsb = '';
        $acc  = '';
        $name = '';

        if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
            $bsb = esc_attr( GFForms::get( $this->id['bsb'], $value ) );
            $acc = esc_attr( GFForms::get( $this->id['acc'], $value ) );
            $name = esc_attr( GFForms::get( $this->id['name'], $value ) );
        }

        $bsb_input = GFFormsModel::get_input( $this, $this->id . '.1' );
        $acc_input = GFFormsModel::get_input( $this, $this->id . '.2' );
        $name_input = GFFormsModel::get_input( $this, $this->id . '.3' );

        // ARIA labels.
        $required_attribute     = $this->isRequired ? 'aria-required="true"' : '';
        $invalid_attribute      = $this->failed_validation ? 'aria-invalid="true"' : 'aria-invalid="false"';
        $describedby_attribute  = $this->get_aria_describedby();
        $input_aria_describedby = '';

        $bsb_tabindex = GFCommon::get_tabindex();
        $acc_tabindex  = GFCommon::get_tabindex();
        $name_tabindex = GFCommon::get_tabindex();

        $bsb_sub_label = DDMWGF_BSB;
        $acc_sub_label = DDMWGF_ACC;
        $name_sub_label = DDMWGF_NAME;

        $bsb_markup = '';
        $acc_markup  = '';
        $name_markup = '';

        if ( $is_sub_label_above ) {

            $style = ( $is_admin && rgar( $bsb_input, 'isHidden' ) ) ? "style='display:none;'" : '';
            if ( $is_admin || ! rgar( $bsb_input, 'isHidden' ) ) {
                $bsb_markup = "<span id='{$field_id}_bsb_container' class='dd_bsb gform-grid-col gform-grid-col--size-auto' {$style}>
                                            <label for='{$field_id}_bsb' class='gform-field-label gform-field-label--type-sub {$sub_label_class}'>{$bsb_sub_label}</label>
                                            <input type='text' name='input_{$id}.1' id='{$field_id}_bsb' value='{$bsb}' {$bsb_tabindex} {$disabled_text} {$required_attribute} {$invalid_attribute} {$describedby_attribute} {$input_aria_describedby}/>
                                        </span>";
            }

            $style = ( $is_admin && rgar( $acc_input, 'isHidden' ) ) ? "style='display:none;'" : '';
            if ( $is_admin || ! rgar( $acc_input, 'isHidden' ) ) {
                $acc_markup = "<span id='{$field_id}_acc_container' class='dd_acc gform-grid-col gform-grid-col--size-auto' {$style}>
                                            <label for='{$field_id}_acc' class='gform-field-label gform-field-label--type-sub {$sub_label_class}'>{$acc_sub_label}</label>
                                            <input type='text' name='input_{$id}.2' id='{$field_id}_acc' value='{$acc}' {$acc_tabindex} {$disabled_text} {$required_attribute} {$invalid_attribute} {$describedby_attribute} {$input_aria_describedby}/>
                                        </span>";
            }

            $style = ( $is_admin && rgar( $name_input, 'isHidden' ) ) ? "style='display:none;'" : '';
            if ( $is_admin || ! rgar( $name_input, 'isHidden' ) ) {
                $name_markup = "<span id='{$field_id}_name_container' class='dd_name gform-grid-col gform-grid-col--size-auto' {$style}>
                                            <label for='{$field_id}_name' class='gform-field-label gform-field-label--type-sub {$sub_label_class}'>{$name_sub_label}</label>
                                            <input type='text' name='input_{$id}.3' id='{$field_id}_name' value='{$name}' {$name_tabindex} {$disabled_text} {$required_attribute} {$invalid_attribute} {$describedby_attribute} {$input_aria_describedby}/>
                                        </span>";
            }

        } else {
            $style = ( $is_admin && rgar( $bsb_input, 'isHidden' ) ) ? "style='display:none;'" : '';
            if ( $is_admin || ! rgar( $bsb_input, 'isHidden' ) ) {
                $bsb_markup = "<span id='{$field_id}_bsb_container' class='dd_bsb gform-grid-col gform-grid-col--size-auto' {$style}>
                                            <input type='text' name='input_{$id}.1' id='{$field_id}_bsb' value='{$bsb}' {$bsb_tabindex} {$disabled_text} {$required_attribute} {$invalid_attribute} {$describedby_attribute} {$input_aria_describedby}/>
                                            <label for='{$field_id}_bsb' class='gform-field-label gform-field-label--type-sub {$sub_label_class}'>{$bsb_sub_label}</label>
                                        </span>";
            }

            $style = ( $is_admin && rgar( $acc_input, 'isHidden' ) ) ? "style='display:none;'" : '';
            if ( $is_admin || ! rgar( $acc_input, 'isHidden' ) ) {
                $acc_markup = "<span id='{$field_id}_acc_container' class='dd_acc gform-grid-col gform-grid-col--size-auto' {$style}>
                                            <input type='text' name='input_{$id}.2' id='{$field_id}_acc' value='{$acc}' {$acc_tabindex} {$disabled_text} {$required_attribute} {$invalid_attribute} {$describedby_attribute} {$input_aria_describedby}/>
                                            <label for='{$field_id}_acc' class='gform-field-label gform-field-label--type-sub {$sub_label_class}'>{$acc_sub_label}</label>
                                        </span>";
            }

            $style = ( $is_admin && rgar( $name_input, 'isHidden' ) ) ? "style='display:none;'" : '';
            if ( $is_admin || ! rgar( $name_input, 'isHidden' ) ) {
                $name_markup = "<span id='{$field_id}_name_container' class='dd_name gform-grid-col gform-grid-col--size-auto' {$style}>
                                            <input type='text' name='input_{$id}.3' id='{$field_id}_name' value='{$name}' {$name_tabindex} {$disabled_text} {$required_attribute} {$invalid_attribute} {$describedby_attribute} {$input_aria_describedby}/>
                                            <label for='{$field_id}_name' class='gform-field-label gform-field-label--type-sub {$sub_label_class}'>{$name_sub_label}</label>
                                        </span>";
            }

        }
        $css_class = $this->get_css_class();

        return "<div class='ginput_complex{$class_suffix} ginput_container ginput_container--dda {$css_class} gform-grid-row' id='{$field_id}'>
                    {$bsb_markup}
                    {$acc_markup}
                    {$name_markup}
                    <div class='gf_clear gf_clear_complex'></div>
                </div>";
    }
    
    public function get_css_class() {

        $css_class = "ginput_container_dd ";

        return trim( $css_class );
    }
    
    public function get_value_entry_detail( $value, $currency = '', $use_text = false, $format = 'html', $media = 'screen' ) {
        if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
            $bsb = trim( rgget( $this->id . '.1', $value ) );
            $acc  = trim( rgget( $this->id . '.2', $value ) );
            $name = trim( rgget( $this->id . '.3', $value ) );

            $return = DDMWGF_BSB . ': ' . $bsb . ', ' . DDMWGF_ACC . ': ' . $acc . ', ' . DDMWGF_NAME . ': ' . $name;

        } else {
            $return = $value;
        }

        if ( $format === 'html' ) {
            $return = esc_html( $return );
        }
        return $return;
    }
    
    public function sanitize_settings() {
        parent::sanitize_settings();
        if ( is_array( $this->inputs ) ) {
            foreach ( $this->inputs as &$input ) {
                if ( isset ( $input['choices'] ) && is_array( $input['choices'] ) ) {
                    $input['choices'] = $this->sanitize_settings_choices( $input['choices'] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public function get_value_export( $entry, $input_id = '', $use_text = false, $is_csv = false ) {
        if ( empty( $input_id ) ) {
            $input_id = $this->id;
        }

        if ( absint( $input_id ) == $input_id ) {
            $return = rgar( $entry, $input_id );
            if ( ! empty( $return ) ) {
                return $return;
            }

            $bsb = trim( rgget( $this->id . '.1', $value ) );
            $acc  = trim( rgget( $this->id . '.2', $value ) );
            $name = trim( rgget( $this->id . '.3', $value ) );

            $return = DDMWGF_BSB . ': ' . $bsb . ', ' . DDMWGF_ACC . ': ' . $acc . ', ' . DDMWGF_NAME . ': ' . $name;

            return $return;
        } else {

            return rgar( $entry, $input_id );
        }
    }
    
}

GF_Fields::register( new DDMWGF_Field_Bank() );
```

(For reference, the constants referred to pull localised strings)

When testing, absolutely no data from any of the 3 fields even attempts to save. Can anyone point me in the right direction re: what I’m missing here?

Thanks :)